# Simulate UITableView Editing exclusive touch behavior

Tags: ios, uitableview

By Default, When the UITableView is in editing state, it shows a delete button, any touch on UITableView will cancel the editing style first. when i create a custom UITableViewCell with a custom gesture which shows a edit button, how do i simulate this exclusiving touch behavior?

Comment: Why you want this touch behaviour? default editing swipe feature working on custom UITableViewCell also.

Comment: because i implemented my own swipe gesture to show custom ui buttons like +1 and -1 in a cart.